# How does the C++ compiler decide which of these functions is called?

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Consider the following setup:

I am given an interface

```
template<class T>
  void FooClass<T>::foo(boost::function<double (int)> f)
{...}
```

I want to implement f using a Functor:

```
class MyFun {
    public: double operator()(int a) {do something...;}
}
```

However there is another function defined in the interface

```
template<class T>
  template <class FunPtr> 
    void FooClass<T>::foo(const FunPtr& f)
{...}
```

When a FooClass object is called,

```
MyFun f;
FooClass<double> fooclass;
fooclass.foo(f);
```

it uses the second definition, while I want it to call the first one - can this be changed somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler *'preferres'* the second definition because the *template version* results in an **exact** match for the function object parameter, whereas the `boost::function` parameter *needs* an **implicit conversion** to be accepted (and implicit conversions are considered *after* direct overload resolution). You can achieve what you want just by constructing a `boost::function` object, and **then** passing it to the function (note that you can do this in the same line, I'm just doing it separately for clarity):

```
boost::function<double (int)> bMyFun(myFunInstance);
fooClassInstance.foo(bMyFun);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly construct a `boost::function` object so the first overload will be preferred:

```
fooclass.foo(boost::function<double (int)>(f));
```

Regarding your question title, are you wondering how overload resolution works? When the overload is being chosen, an untemplated type is a better match than a templated one, but a templated type that matches directly (`FunPtr = MyFun`) is a better match than an an implictit conversion (`MyFun -> boost::function<double(int)>`), so the second overload matches better in your original case.

(Thanks to @David for pointing out a glaring error in my original formulation!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not very familiar with these concepts, so for now I only wonder how this works in this specific example.

Comment: *Potential implicit conversion chains aren't considered until after an overload has been chosen.*??? They are considered, and that is how the best overload is found. The problem in the question is that the templated version will be a better match than anything that requires a conversion, but overload resolution will consider both and then decide for the template.

Comment: @David: The template is chosen because that's a better match -- if conversion were considered first, then the function would be considered convertible to `boost::function` and the first overload would be a better match, wouldn't it?

Comment: @David: Right, I see, the potential for the conversion is already considered, but the implicitly convertible type is worse than the on-the-nose template match. That was badly written, let me edit that.

Comment: Now it is right, both of them will be checked for overload resolution, where the template is an exact match, and the non-template requires a conversion. That makes the template a better option. Compare it with the explicit conversion in your code, where again both are considered, and both are perfect matches (with the template argument would be: `FunPtr == boost::function<double(int)>`) In this case, because they are both *perfect* matches, the compiler will prefer the non-templated. The preference of template/non-template is performed *after* the conversion chains have been considered.